# Reading a file from an alternate location

Tags: linux

I have a certain file (data.abc) located in, say, my home folder. I make a copy of it to another location (for example, "/mnt/ramtemp/").

Whenever the file in my home folder is accessed by any process, I want it to be read not from home folder, but from "/mnt/ramtemp/". As you might have guessed from the path of the latter, it is where I mount the ramfs. So, basically, I want a process to access not the file on my HDD (which is slower), but its copy on ramfs (which is way faster). At the same time, I want the file data.abc to remain in my home folder under that name, I don't want to rename or delete it. Is there any way I could guide the system to redirect the processes to read the file from alternative location whenever they try to read it from home folder?

Comment: Just wondering what you've tried so far?  Is the process locked to access it from your home folder?  If so would a simple symlink work?

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother! Any modern OS worth its salt (and most certainly Linux) is already automatically doing exactly what you are describing, and even without creating ramdisk.

Any access to disk is automatically cached in memory, such that all subsequent accesses to your files do not need to re-read it from disk. However, it *may* stop doing that if memory is coming in very short supply.

Actually, creating big ramdisk is most likely to make it work SLOWER, not faster, because virtual memory subsystem can make use of that precious memory much more efficiently than ramdisk ever could.

Comment: automatic caching often removes the file from cache, especially if i use up lots of ram, and it has to re-read it from HDD. I want to ensure that the file remains in RAM no matter how much RAM I use and what other files and how often I use

Comment: Linux caching algorithm is much smarter than you might think. If you measure your actual long-term performance using standard Linux caching vs. your ramdisk caching, you are most likely to lose overall. Yes, if memory comes really short, it may evict your files from cache, but keeping them in ramdisk is likely to make overall performance even slower.

Comment: I guess I'll have to use some caching techniques then. Like a script that accesses the needed files often to make system leave them in cache